# Difference between array of middlewares and compose-middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was suggested to use [compose-middleware](https://github.com/blakeembrey/compose-middleware) module to have an array of middlewares. 
Then I noticed this works just fine with express.js:

```
router.post('/editPassword', doAction ); 

var doAction = [
   function(req, res, next){
      //whatever
      next();
   },

   function(req, res, next){
      //whatever
   }
]
```

What's the main advantage of using compose-middleware then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for previous versions of express, but this module is pointless in express 4.

As stated in the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) for `app.use`:

> **app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])**
>
> [...]
>
> callback  Callback functions; can be:
>
> - A middleware function.
> - A series of middleware functions (separated by commas).
> - **An array of middleware functions.**
> - A combination of all of the above.

It means that you can pass an array of middlewares to it and express will handle them seamlessly, "composing" them.

Routers implement the same interface, so your example is working as designed.